# Python/Flask : psutil date ranges

Tags: python, flask, psutil

I'm currently writing a web application using Flask in python that generates the linux/nix performances(CPU, Disk Usage, Memory Usage). I already implemented the python library psutil.

My question is how can I get the values of each util with date ranges. For example: Last 3 hours of CPU, Disk Usage, Memory usage.

Sorry for the question I'm a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 0):

For future need, I found a way to this. Using ElasticSearch and Psutil.

I indexed the psutil values to elasticsearch then used the date-range and date-histogram aggs.

Thanks!